# class-transformer Exclude undefined properties

Tags: typescript, class-transformer

Exclude undefined or null properties from the class. this is actual nature but I need a decorator who can ignore this

```
import {Expose, plainToClass} from "class-transformer";

class User {
    @Expose() id: number;
    @Expose() firstName: string;
    @Expose() lastName: string;
}

const fromPlainUser = {
  unkownProp: 'hello there',
  firstName: 'Umed',
  lastName: 'Khudoiberdiev',
}

console.log(plainToClass(User, fromPlainUser, { excludeExtraneousValues: true }))

// User {
//   id: undefined,
//   firstName: 'Umed',
//   lastName: 'Khudoiberdiev'
// }
```

Comment: What's the purpose of excluding them since they are part of your class?

Comment: i am using Nestjs with mongoose and passing it to mongoose query

Comment: Seems that `class-transformer` does not have some decorator to exclude only undefined properties, it makes sense since your class `User` define a precise type and excluding one of its properties transform it to another type. You can try removing `id` from `User` and do not use `{ excludeExtraneousValues: true }`

Comment: Hi Akash, i have a problem with this as well. Please keep an eye on:
https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/35.
Maybe refer with a comment to this (i did it too) so they consider it important enough to implement..

Answer (score 2):

add **exposeUnsetFields** to your options plain object. Should be:

```js
plainToClass(User, fromPlainUser, { excludeExtraneousValues: true, exposeUnsetFields: false, })
```

Comment: this only works for undefined, not null

Answer (score 1):

If you create a class instance then you'll have its properties. If you want to have an object without undefined properties - simply convert a class instance back to a plain object with rules that avoid undefined fields.
It won't be a class instance anymore, but it will be an object without undefined fields.